# How do I remove the header in a Kafka (Spring-boot)?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I need to send a message to a specific Kafka topic.
I use the following KafkaTemplate to do this:
KafkaTemplate<String, RequestDto>

The following parameters are put in the Kafka producer:

```
private ProducerFactory<String, RequestDto> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
}
```

Creating a Producer:

```
    public KafkaTemplate<String, RequestDto> kafkaTemplate() {
        KafkaTemplate<String, RequestDto> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerConfigs());
        template.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }
```

And when I execute the "send" method, I have a message sent to the Kafka topic, but at the same time I send the header, which contains the path to the DTO file of the request.

```
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, RequestDto>> result = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, requestDto);
```

[Example header in offset explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4zIf.png)

Because of this header something breaks in the application, which is a consumer and I can't do anything about it. Is there any way to remove this header from the query?

Comment: Where are you actually inserting a header? You're going to have to show the consumer code that is breaking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [DefaultKafkaProducerFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.html) by adding [JsonSerializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/JsonSerializer.html) with `ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS` false

```
JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
jsonSerializer.setAddTypeInfo​(false);  //
```

Set to false to disable adding type info headers.

And then create `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` with key and value serializer

```
return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props,new StringSerializer(),jsonSerializer);
```

You can also disable this properties through producer side by [Configuration Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#serdes-json-config)

> JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS (default true): You can set it to false to disable this feature on the JsonSerializer (sets the addTypeInfo property).

And to ignore during consumer side

> JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS (default true): You can set it to false to ignore headers set by the serializer.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the sending of the header in Kafka messages, this property is configured in the producer, which prevents the **TypeId** from being present in the Headers

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.add.type.headers=false
```